# velocity + jasmin unit test on meteor server side

Tags: meteor, jasmine, velocity

I am trying to use velocity and jasmine-unit to execute some tests on the server side of my meteor app.

The test script looks like this:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // User test class
    //

    function UserTestingClass () {}

    UserTestingClass.prototype = {
        constructor: UserTestingClass,

        createAdmin:
        {
            createCall: function(email, pass, fname, lname, photo, tel, saloon_id, userRole, userInfo)
            {
                Meteor.call('addUser', email, pass, fname, lname, photo, tel, saloon_id, userRole, userInfo, function(e, r)
                {
                    return r;
                });
            }
        }
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // User tests
    //

    describe("UserTestingClass", function ()
    {
        it("create an admin user", function ()
        {
            var userTest = new UserTestingClass();

            expect(userTest.createAdmin
                .createCall("asd@asd.asd", "asdasd", "john", "doe", "image", "0701111111", "ididididid", "admin", "info admin john"))
                .not
                .toBe(undefined);
        });
    });
})();
```

And the server side code of my meteor app:

```
addUser: function(email, pass, fname, lname, photo, tel, pv_id, role, info)
    {
        var id =
        Accounts.createUser(
        {
            email: email,
            password: pass,
            profile:
            {
                firstname: fname,
                lastname: lname,
                photo: photo,
                tel: tel,
                other:
                {
                    id: pv_id,
                    role: role,
                    info: info
                }
            }
        });

        return id;
    }
```

And my problem is that I'm not getting the id of the created user returned but always undefined. I believe that I need help with how to test returned data on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my tutorial https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/creating-and-testing-meteor-applications-with-bdd-using-velocity-and-jasmine/ it's a bit long, but just search for meteor.call and it will show you how to test server code with jasmine-unity.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Good tutorial but are inserts not really being inserted? I do get green in chapter 2 but I do not see any tutorial collection in mongoDB.

Comment: Velocity is running test on a parallel instance running on port 5000 - guessing it also uses a different mongodb instance.